# How to workaround parent-child script without using classic way, or without using where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for workaround that works like parent-child, but without using recursive searching. I am not able to use temporary tables.

THIS SCRIPT WORKS but slowly, always run for 600 sec.:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT party_id as ANCESTOR, 
       party_id, role_id, subject_id
FROM onecrm.CRM_PARTY 
WHERE LEVEL>1 
and party_id = 'text'
CONNECT BY PRIOR Party_id=parent_id;
```

This works well, but it contain 3 steps. I need to use only one step because of aggregate tasks.

```
select internal_id, party_id, parent_id, subject_id, channel_type_id 
from onecrm.O_ORDER oo 
  join onecrm.CRM_PARTY cp on oo.party_ref_no = cp.party_ref_no 
where internal_id = 'O7VYECF';
```

Result:

```
INTERNAL_ID, PARTY_ID, PARENT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, CHANNEL_TYPE_ID
O7VYECF     110179237   110179236  null           CRM
```

```
select internal_id, cp.party_id, parent_id
from onecrm.O_ORDER oo 
  right join onecrm.CRM_PARTY cp on oo.party_ref_no = cp.party_ref_no 
where cp.party_id = '110179236';
```

Result:

```
INTERNAL_ID, PARTY_ID, PARENT_ID
OAMUAY7      110179236  null
```

```
select internal_id, cp.party_id, parent_id, cp.subject_id, 
       channel_type_id, full_name, phone_no_1, phone_no_2, email, segment
from onecrm.O_ORDER oo 
  right join onecrm.CRM_PARTY cp on oo.party_ref_no = cp.party_ref_no 
  left join onecrm.CRM_SUBJECT cs on cs.SUBJECT_ID = cp.SUBJECT_ID
  left join onecrm.crm_contact_ref ccr on ccr.conre_ref_no = cs.subj_ref_no
  left join onecrm.CRM_CONTACT_EXT cce on cce.contact_id = ccr.contact_id 
where cp.party_id = '110179236';
```

Expected result:

```
INTERNAL_ID, PARTY_ID, PARENT_ID, SUBJECT_ID, CHANNEL_TYPE_ID, FULL_NAME, PHONE_NO_1, PHONE_NO_2, EMAIL, SEGMENT

OAMUAY7   110179236 null    102219217   TGB great_company s.r.o.                
xxx            xxx      TNC     RNC
```

Expected result is write only `internal_id` and get `parent_id` INFO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `connect by` query has no `start with` clause. This means it's calculating the tree for *every single row* in the table!

It's then applying the `where` clause to the tree generated.

For example the following builds a tree start for the rows C1 = 1, C1 = 2, & C1 = 3:

```
create table t as 
  select level c1, level - 1 c2 
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 3;

select t.*, 
       connect_by_root c1 rt
from   t
connect by prior c1 = c2;

C1    C2    RT   
    1     0     1 
    2     1     1 
    3     2     1 
    2     1     2 
    3     2     2 
    3     2     3
```

As you load more data into the table, this will very quickly slow your query to a crawl.

Even if your where clause means you only get a few rows back, you're very likely to be processing a huge data set.

To avoid this, you almost certainly want a `start with` clause. This defines which row is the root of the tree:

```
select t.*, 
       connect_by_root c1 rt
from   t
start  with c1 = 1
connect by prior c1 = c2;

C1    C2    RT   
    1     0     1 
    2     1     1 
    3     2     1
```